# Swiftmailer does not work after changing from Dev to Prod env

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

Basically while my web app was in Dev env it has been working correctly. This is the only reason i can think of that changed before it stopped sending emails.

Swifmailer is being used for sending confirmation emails and handling support emails to my original email.

After moving from Dev to Prod it no longer sends any emails.

Credentials have been checked and confirmed to be correct.

Website runs on Symfony 2 I think.

What may cause that? 
Also if you need any code, just let me know which file since I have no clue what may be needed.

Thank you for the help

Edit #1:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    port: '%mailer_port%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
    logging: true
# delivery_addresses: ['']
```

parameters:

```
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_port: 465 
    mailer_host: correct host
    mailer_user: my email user@domain
    mailer_password: mypassword
```

Comment: Would be useful to see your swiftmailer config

Comment: Added #1, let me know if you need more

Comment: Can any one help ? :<